# Largest 3 numbers in a sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, sequence

I am trying to find out the largest 3 values in a sequence but from my code I do not understand if I were to put in largest_three([9,6,4,1,2,3,10,8,7]), it would give an answer of [6, 9, 10] instead of [8,9,10]. From my understanding, from my code, I'll let the largest_3 to be some random number in the sequence and if that number is not the same value as largest_2 and largest, it would replace the current largest_3 number. But from this code, if there were to be a duplicate of numbers, my code would not work. How do I rewrite my code such that my code is able to find out the largest three numbers in a sequence and allows for duplicate largest numbers?

I am allowed to create one tuple to return my answer and one list and not allowed to modify the original sequence.

```
def largest_three(seq):
    largest = seq[0]
    largest_2 = seq[0]
    largest_3 = seq[1]
    answer = []
    for num,item in enumerate(seq):
        if seq[num] > largest:
            largest = seq[num]
 
    for num,item in enumerate(seq):
        if seq[num] > largest_2 and not largest:
            largest_2 = seq[num]
            
    for num,item in enumerate(seq):
        if seq[num] > largest_3 and not largest_2 and not largest:
            largest_3 = seq[num]
    answer.append(largest_3)
    answer.append(largest_2)
    answer.append(largest)
    return answer
```

Comment: If you explicitly sort the first three numbers of your list, your algorithm will work. And I suspect you meant to do `largest_3 = seq[2]` instead of `seq[1]`.

Comment: I think you also meant `and seq[num] != largest` instead of `and not largest` (and the same for the third loop).

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helps you, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code:

1. When initializing your largest 3 numbers, you should

```py
largest = seq[0]
largest_2 = seq[1] # the index here was 0
largest_3 = seq[2] # the index here was 1
```

2. In your second and third for-loop, the first if-statement condition is correct, however the ones following it isn't. `not largest` for any int `largest` simply returns true if the int is not 0. You should be using this instead:

```py
if seq[num] > largest_2 and seq[num] != largest:
```

and

```py
if seq[num] > largest_3 and seq[num] != largest_2 and seq[num] != largest:
```

3. Finally, your function would work after the two changes mentioned above:

```py
def largest_three(seq):
    largest = seq[0]
    largest_2 = seq[1]
    largest_3 = seq[2]
    answer = []
    for num, item in enumerate(seq):
        if seq[num] > largest:
            largest = seq[num]

    for num, item in enumerate(seq):
        if seq[num] > largest_2 and seq[num] != largest:
            largest_2 = seq[num]

    for num, item in enumerate(seq):
        if seq[num] > largest_3 and seq[num] != largest_2 and seq[num] != largest:
            largest_3 = seq[num]
    answer.append(largest_3)
    answer.append(largest_2)
    answer.append(largest)
    return answer
```

Console:

```py
>>> largest_three([9, 6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 10, 8, 7])
[8, 9, 10]
```

---

Simplest way if you allowed to use `sorted`:

```py
res = sorted([9, 6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 10, 8, 7], reverse=True)[:3]
```

Comment: the `sorted` method won't work without some extra care for lists where the largest three numbers are not in sequence

Comment: @Chase, you need to explain that a little better, since sorting is what *puts* them in sequence.

Comment: @paxdiablo I thought by largest in sequence meant the largest 3 values that are also in numerical order

Comment: @Chase, I assume from your comment to my answer you mean contiguous rather then in numerical order, since 100, 200, 300 satisfies the latter but not the former. In any case, I don't believe that's the correct interpretation, OP asked for just the largest three values.

Comment: I'm not keen on (1)  iterating over the list three times when a simple sort will do; and (2) enumerating index and key when you only use index. But I can hardly downvote you for that since it was in the question :-)

Comment: @paxidiablo Yea the whole problem can be accomplished by one line, but I think what OP wants is how to **fix** his own function.

Answer (score 0):

That's a large amount of code for a relatively simple task. You can actually do this with some much more concise code, by sorting a copy of the list and just returning the last three values.

The `oldList` parameter is obviously the list you want to examine. For the other two parameters (that default to true), `allowDupes` will leave duplicates in when getting the highest three values (they'll be removed otherwise), and `highToLow` with return the highest entries in descending order (otherwise ascending):

```
def largest_three(oldList, allowDupes = True, highToLow = True):
    # Copy to sorted list either with or without duplicates.

    if allowDupes:
        sortedList = list(oldList)
    else:
        sortedList = list(set(oldList))

    # For high value first, reverse sort and return tuple of first three.

    if highToLow:
        sortedList.sort(reverse = True)
        return tuple(sortedList[:3])

    # Otherwise, normal sort and return tuple of last three.

    sortedList.sort(reverse = False)
    return tuple(sortedList[-3:])

# Test harness.

print(largest_three([9,6,4,1,2,3,10,8,7]))
print(largest_three([9,6,9,9,9,9,9,4,1,2,3,10,8,7]))
print(largest_three([9,6,9,9,9,9,9,4,1,2,3,10,8,7], False))
print(largest_three([9,6,9,9,9,9,9,4,1,2,3,10,8,7], highToLow = False))
print(largest_three([9,6,9,9,9,9,9,4,1,2,3,10,8,7], False, False))
```

That gives, as expected:

```
(10, 9, 8)
(10, 9, 9)
(10, 9, 8)
(9, 9, 10)
(8, 9, 10)
```

This code covers *all* your requirements bar one (and it even covers that one if you always allow duplicates):

- Returns largest three values (with duplicates or not);
- Does not modify original list;
- Creates only one extra list and a tuple that gets returned (unless you need the duplicate removal in which case it also creates a set).

Comment: What if the largest three values are not in sequence? `[10, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1]` - according to OP - that should return `[5, 6, 7]` not `[6, 7, 10]`

Comment: @Chase: the "largest 3 values in a sequence" `[10, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1]` are `6, 7, 10`, *not* `5, 6, 7`. I'm not sure why you think the latter is correct, OP doesn't mention that case at all.

Comment: @Chase I think you misunderstood what OP meant. The "sequence" OP mentioned in simply the input list.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using `numpy.partition` which does exactly what you want. Check the documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html).